# How to call function via interface from another contract when calldata type is used

Tags: solidity, addresses, calldata

I have declared the following interface:

```
interface Test {
    function airDropMultiple(
        address[] calldata recipients,
        uint[] calldata tokenAmount
    )
        external
        returns (bool);
}
```

I am attempting to call it like this:

```
Test(ContractAddress).airDropMultiple(
    [testWalletAddress[4], testWalletAddress[3]],
    [10**18, 10**19]
);
```

I am receiving the following compiler error:

```
Invalid implicit conversion from address[2] memory to address[] memory requested.
```

How I can call this interface from this contract to target contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general error:

```
Invalid implicit conversion from type[N] memory to type[] memory requested.
```

Occurs when trying to send a static array to a function which expects a dynamic array.

In order to fix it in your specific case, you should do something like:

```
address[] memory recipients = new address[](2);
uint[] memory tokenAmounts = new uint[](2);
(recipients[0], recipients[1]) = (testWalletAddress[4], testWalletAddress[3]);
(tokenAmounts[0], tokenAmounts[1]) = (10**18, 10**19);
Test(ContractAddress).airDropMultiple(recipients, tokenAmounts);
```